# ¿Cual es la prioridad para aplicar métodos a un objeto en python?

Tags: python, poo

Por ejemplo, si tuviera un objeto tipo lista y quisiera aplicarle métodos tal que le agregue un número entero al azar (del 1 al 10) y que luego calcule el cuadrado de ese elemento y retorne solo el numero al cuadrado (entero), tengo el mente algo de esta forma

```
 lista.crear().agregar(numeroRandom(1,10)).calculaCuadrado(lista.elemento(0))
```

Se que es muy sencillo realmente, pero soy nuevo en este mundo y no entiendo si tiene prioridad de izquierda a derecha o los paréntesis o algo por el estilo

Comment: Aclara el lenguaje

Comment: @Japv el lenguaje es python

Comment: Se evalúa de izquierda a derecha. Por ejemplo `lista.crear().agregar()` invocaría el método `agregar()` sobre el objeto devuelto por `lista.crear()`. Para que este tipo de encadenamientos te funcione, por tanto, cada uno de esos métodos debería retornar una referencia al propio objeto, para que sobre ese valor retornado se pueda aplicar el siguiente método. Naturalmente si alguno de los parámetros que pasas al méodo invoca otra llamada (como `numeroRandom()`) esa invocación se resuelve antes para poder pasar el resultado.